# preg_replace not retrieving correct data

Tags: php

I'm using my own cms from scratch, so, i'm adding useful functions for my system, but i got stuck on this:

A phrase is being loaded from lang file on array, in this case, `$lang['sign']['server'] = 'Sign in with your {{servername}} registered account:';`, and then, by a function, `{{servername}}` must be replaced by `$config['servername']`.

What i have so far on my functions class is the following:

```
public function replaceTags($text)
{
global $config;
return preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/" , $config[strtolower("$1")], $text) ;
}
```

Im calling this function here: `$main->set('ssocial', $FUNC->replaceTags($lang['sign']['social']));`, but the result is `Sign in with your registered account:` instead of `Sign in with your "Server Name Goes Here" registered account`.

Any ideas about why the preg_replace is not retrieving the value?

Also, when `$config[”$1”]` is inside '' like this `'$config[”$1”]'`, the output is `Sign in with your $config[”servername”] registered account:`, so i have no clues about what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/' ... )` maybe? `{ }` denote match recurrence in RegExps... though I'm not sure it'll fail without something to match before (not actually tested it).

Comment: As for `$config[”$1”] is inside '' like this '$config[”$1”]'` ... that's to be expected, apostrophes denote non-interpolated strings (e.g. $sausage will be treated literally as $sausage *not* the variable $sausage).

Comment: The output is the same changing the regex, empty; i've tried with different stuff (before with %tag%), but everytime the output goes blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty working example using preg_replace_callback

```
<?php

$config = array('server' => 'my custom text');

function handler($matches){
    global $config;
    return $config[$matches[1]];
}

function replaceTags($text)
{
    return preg_replace_callback("/{{(.*?)}}/" , 'handler', $text) ;
}


print replaceTags("Hello {{server}}");
```

Output:

```
Hello my custom text
```

As for why your code doesn't work: the second parameter of preg_replace is $config[strtolower("$1")], so php will literally look for key `"$1"` in `$config`, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, and for preg_replace, that was my kinda first attempt...